# JQuery Tablesorter with newer JQuery version

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I'm trying to use the Tablesorter plugin with Wordpress' version of JQuery, version 1.7.2.  This is not working, and I've narrowed it down to incompatibility with the JQuery version by taking one of the demos (demo.html, in fact), uploading it and the associated files to my web server, testing to make sure that it works, and then replacing this line:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-latest.js"></script>`

with this:

`<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.example.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.2'></script>`

(as that is the resulting line from loading JQuery in WordPress).  I don't want to load JQuery from another source, as I'd like to stay within the WordPress ecosystem for such libraries in the name of compatibility.

Honestly, it's not even a matter of making the Tablesorter plugin work with newer JQuery releases, I just want a way to sort tables, and this seemed like the go-to way.  I'm open to ideas of how I can either make this work, or any other way that I can sort some tables.

I posted this here, and not to the WordPress Stack Exchange, as it seems to be more of a JQuery question than a WordPress question (although asking there about a way to sort tables might not be a bad idea..)

Thanks!

Comment: are you happen to see [DataTables](http://datatables.net/) ?

Comment: Interesting. I'll need to look into it a bit more.  I really, only, want table sorting, and it looks like this comes with a lot more which would detract from the experience I'm looking for.  However, that all seems to be capable of disabling, so it might be the right road to go down.

Comment: Try using my fork of [tablesorter](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/)

Comment: @Mottie Your fork also doesn't work with the WordPress-included JQuery 1.7.2.  In the interest of science, I tried it also with Google API's JQuery 1.7.2, and it worked.  So I'm confused.

Comment: @Mottie I suspect this might have something to do with WordPress' JQuery being in noConflict mode.

Comment: I've run into some issues with WordPress addons loading jQuery more than once. When that happens, the `jQuery` and/or `$` variable are only associated with the last loaded copy while the jQuery plugins are associated with the first because of loading order. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @Mottie This is not the issue here - I've confirmed that jQuery is only being loaded once.  The issue seems to be the noConflict mode.  (DataTables, for instance, did not work using $, but did work in when accessed in no conflict mode [i.e. `var $j = jQuery.noConflict();` and references to $j).

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? You do understand that no conflict mode means the `$` is reverted back to it's previous value, it's value before jQuery was loaded? So if you want to use jQuery, you'll have to use the no conflict mode variable (`$j` in the example above) or `jQuery`.